# What is the difference between "find" and "till" in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I see I can use <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to move to the next / previous character `c`

I can also use <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to move to the next / previous character `c`

Is the only difference between them that <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> places the cursor before the character, <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (going backwards) places the cursor *after* the character and <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> both place it on the character itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only different between them is cursor position. From `:help motion.txt`:

```
                                                  f
f{char}             To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right. The                                                         
                    cursor is placed on {char} inclusive.                                                                         
                    {char} can be entered as a digraph digraph-arg.                                                               
                    When 'encoding' is set to Unicode, composing                                                                  
                    characters may be used, see utf-8-char-arg.                                                                   
                    :lmap mappings apply to {char}.  The CTRL-^ command                                                           
                    in Insert mode can be used to switch this on/off                                                              
                    i_CTRL-^.                                                                                                     

                                                   F                                                                             
F{char}             To the [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the left.                                                           
                    The cursor is placed on {char} exclusive.                                                                     
                    {char} can be entered like with the f command.                                                                

                                                   t                                                                             
t{char}             Till before [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the                                                            
                    right.  The cursor is placed on the character left of                                                         
                    {char} inclusive.                                                                                             
                    {char} can be entered like with the f command.                                                                

                                                   T                                                                             
T{char}             Till after [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the                                                             
                    left.  The cursor is placed on the character right of                                                         
                    {char} exclusive.                                                                                             
                    {char} can be entered like with the f command.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes the main difference between them is the cursor position as you said.

This comes in handy when you want to delete or change some characters for example. Suppose you have the following line:

```
print "Hello, world!\n"; exit
```

Suppose you want to change everything before the semicolon. To do that, you go to the beginning of the line (<kbd>^</kbd>) and then <kbd>c</kbd>hange everything <kbd>t</kbd>ill the semicolon.

If instead, you wanted to remove the first command and just leave the `exit`, you would <kbd>d</kbd>elete everything by <kbd>f</kbd>inding the semicolon.

In short, <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> are what `vim` calls motion commands. They help modify the operator before them. When you motion an operator with <kbd>f</kbd> it operates on all characters between the current cursor position up to *and including* the character you motioned to with <kbd>f</kbd>. If you chose <kbd>t</kbd> instead, your operator would operate on everything from the current position up to *and excluding* the character you motioned to with <kbd>t</kbd>.